# Screen reader (NVDA) loses focus after hitting Enter on pagination element

Tags: reactjs, screen-readers, nvda

I have a pagination carousel. left arrow, page numbers and right arrow. Once I move focus with shift and hit the enter I change the page, but screen reader is empty and narrator doesn't say anything.

I need to accomplish one of these:

1. After the enter button hit screen reader says the title of the page OR
2. It says the page number and "Please press shift to hear to the title of the page.

The title name is the parent component and the pagination carousel is the component below.

```
render (
    ‹div> 
        <span>
           <span role="button" tabIndex="1" aria-label="previous page" onClick={this.decreaseItr}>
           {this.pagination ()} 
           <span role="button" tabIndex="1" aria-label="previous page" onClick={this.increaseItr}>
        </span>
    </div>
    );
}
```

It is a government application but if you need additional code I will try to provide as much as I can.

I tried to use arial-live and play around with arial-label.